# Does scala compiler converts the type of an object dynamically (at run time)

Tags: scala

In following code, `a` is declared as `AnyRef` but its type check for type `String` is also true. Does Scala compiler convert the type of an object at runtime?

```
scala> val a:AnyRef = "hello"
a: AnyRef = hello

scala> a.isInstanceOf[String]
res6: Boolean = true

scala> a.isInstanceOf[Any]
res8: Boolean = true

scala> a.isInstanceOf[AnyRef]
res9: Boolean = true

scala> a.isInstanceOf[Object]
res12: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Why do you think this is a conversion? Looks like normal inheritance

Comment: OK, `converting` might be a wrong way to put it. As I am declaring `a` as `AnyRef`, it seems the compiler is dynamically assessing the value and treating `a` as a `String`. I am not facing any issues with the code, just trying to understand the behavior.

Comment: The compiler doesn't do *anything* at run time, it only does something at *compile time*. It doesn't even have to *exist* at run time.

Comment: So at compile time, the compiler decides that `a` could be treated as a `String`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two different concepts involved: static (compile-time) type and runtime type. By declaring `val a: AnyRef` you only affect its static type, but at runtime its value is `"hello"` and so the runtime type is `String`. `isInstanceOf` tests the runtime type.

The *compiler* is not "assessing the value and treating `a` as a `String`"; the JVM is.